# Is matching a regex thread unsafe?

Tags: c++, regex, multithreading

I have this really small function that seems to cause a segmentation fault in some of my threads, but my code works just fine, if I add a lock guard to the calls of this function:

```
int getROCIndexByName(const std::string& t_name)
{
   std::smatch match;
   std::regex_match(t_name, match, std::regex(R"(.*ROC ?(\d+))"));
   return std::stoi(match[1].str()) - 1;
}
```

Can this somehow be thread unsafe, or am I just somehow luckily blocking my code by adding guards around this? Thank you!

Comment: Just a comment, but this code has no error handling. What if it gets passed a string that does not match the regex?

Comment: Accessing match[1] without a match might be getting fixed by a lock guard just because it adds more data to the stack. Then match[1] would be reading data from the lock guard instead of causing an error.

Comment: @ZanLynx Well, `std:stoi` threw an `std::invalid_argument` when no matches were found. Was it just luck again? :D

Comment: Yes just luck. Reading from an array that does not exist is Undefined Behavior, so anything can happen. From a technical explanation, it would depend on how close your thread was to the end of the stack, the "stack guard".

Comment: Other than the possible invalid arg exception, the function itself should be thread safe. All local variables. If you were to use static vars however, that is not thread safe.

Comment: It's possible the string you have a reference to is going away during your use of it.  You could try taking the string by value instead of by reference.. though this could change other timings... debugging threads is challenging.

Comment: @sin well, I construct t_name from a c style string literal, can that be a problem?

Comment: It depends on where the t_name is declared and used. If the caller and owner is the thread function, then it's no problem. Ideally, you want to isolate parameters to the thread function.

Comment: Just make certain that everything used in your threads lives at least as long as the thread does. If it doesn't have enough lifetime, then make copies of it before passing it into a thread. String literals have program lifetime because they are read-only memory that is part of the program image, just like your machine code. They won't go away. (If they're in a DLL, *then* you can have problems if the DLL unloads.)

Comment: @sin The owner is a lambda which is called by all of the threads. Threads should have separate stacks when calling lamdas, right? Is the string literal shared somehow?

Comment: String literals have a storage class. If used between threads, they should be declared _const_, read only.

Comment: I use a custom thread _class_ which is self contained data and thread function.

Comment: well, I use a messy design right now, this is the async logic: https://pastebin.com/qBz1jshh
It works with the stupid-lock and does not work without it :D

Comment: General form I use in windows `class CMyThread {
 CWinThread *pThd; 
BOOL Begin();
protected:
 static UINT ThreadFunc( LPVOID pParam );
};
BOOL CMyThread::Begin() {
 pThd = AfxBeginThread(
  ThreadFunc,
  (LPVOID)this,
  THREAD_PRIORITY_NORMAL,
  0,
  CREATE_SUSPENDED,
  NULL  
 );
 pThd->ResumeThread();
}
UINT CMyThread::ThreadFunc( LPVOID pParam )
{
 CMyThread *pThis = reinterpret_cast<CMyThread *>(pParam);
}` Then you create as many objects as you need.

Comment: Well, since then, adding a mutex to this regex matcher never crashed, but removing it results a ~100% chance of crashing, so I'll keep thinking that this is somehow not thread safe...

Answer (score 0):

You should check that there was a match indeed before accessing match[1].

Comment: This is not an answer, it should be a comment. I know that there is indeed always a match.